# Can any one tell me about the script or the seals please? (Characters identified: 藍鳥深竹 癸亥年 二月 興利)

Tags: characters, character-identification

[image]

I would like to know what the script says and also what the seals denote. The seals are red on the painting but I have changed the colour to make them easier to read.

Comment: Best guess: 藍鳥深竹 癸亥年 二月. Artist: 陳興利(畫). First seal too faded out to make out; best guess: 陳奇傑印.

Comment: bingo :) you "should" write the answer, with explanation in details :)

Comment: @martin, do you have a photo of the whole painting?

Answer (score 1):

as @droooze pointed out, the text is:

> 藍鳥深竹
>
> 癸亥年　二月　興利

the first seal is "陳奇傑印"

the second one is "陳興利畫"

"藍鳥深竹" is the painting's title, roughly

blue (藍) bird (鳥) [in] bamboo forest (深竹)

"癸亥年" is 1983 - 60i (i is integer), eg 1983, 1923, . . .

"二月" is february

together, the painting is drawn in the february of 1983 (or 1923, . . .)

"陳奇傑印" means the seal (印) of mr 陳 (surname) 奇傑 (name)

"陳興利畫" means drawn (畫) by mr 陳 (surname) 興利 (name)

most likely, mr 陳 used 2 names here.

have fun :)

Comment: You think it's 傑 too? I can't see it properly...

Comment: well, there're limited choice of character with radical 人 at the left, with bottom-right component of 木. without clearer photo, i support your find :)

Comment: btw, the texture of the background, i suspected it's drawn on a canvas, so, it's most likely in 1983.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. The painting is not on canvas, probably man made looks like silk but isn't. It is indeed two blue birds on bamboo.  Can you say what an anglicized version of the artists name might be?

Comment: romanisation of the names mentioned is, hard to guess, without knowing more. e.g. 陳 would be tan (south-east asia style), chan (cantonese style) or chen (mandarin style).